# Tor Exit Relay safe to use?

Tags: security, exit-relays

I have gone against advice and set up an exit relay. Let's face it more are needed and I am happy to help, I have unlimited broadband and can not think of any better way to use it!

I wanted to know, is it ok for me to continue to use the same PC for normal internet use? Or should I use an entirely different PC for my own use?
Is it safe to use your own personal PC or Laptop as a Tor Exit Relay? And also for shopping etc?
Or is it unsafe to use a PC assigned as a Tor exit relay for personal use?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so, but keep in mind the things that other people can do through your exit relay.
You have to be a bit prepared for things that can arise.
You can use your 'regular' computer for it, but if you do then try to run it with as much uptime as possible to help the network.

There is a guide here with information on what to expect when running a exit node:
https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq-abuse.html.en#TypicalAbuses

If you get second thoughts then you can run a bridge relay or as a 'internal' non-exit node.